# Java RCP/SWT - "Android Toast like" dialog in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, rcp, toast

Does anybody know if there exist some implementation of some popup window, something like in Android: TOAST ?

Comment: Mylyn has something that is shows notifications which fade - I don't know if that may meet your needs though.

Comment: Do you know exactly what package or class it is ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not

Comment: You can use [Eclipse Plugin Spy](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy) to get more information about the implementation details.

Comment: @kon The Plug-in Spy won't help here, it is limited to _workbench parts_. Mylyn notifications are just shells that _live_ outside the workbench.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 5):

The notifications are part of [Mylyn commons](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/mylyn.commons).

To integrate them, add the *Mylyn Commons Notifications* feature from http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest to your target platform definition. The relevant bundles are

- `org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.ui`
- `org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.core`.

You can add a `category` and an `event` to the notifications extension point like this:

```xml
</extension>
  <extension
        point="org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.ui.notifications">
     <category
           icon="icons/obj16/repository.gif"
           id="myNotificationCategory"
           label="My Category">
     </category>
     <event
           categoryId="myNotificationCategory"
           icon="icons/obj16/some-image.gif"
           id="myEvent"
           label="Hello World">
        <defaultHandler
              sinkId="org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.sink.Popup">
        </defaultHandler>
        <description>
          This is the description of the event.
        </description>
     </event>
</extension>
```

To trigger a notification, use the `NotificationService` like this:

```java
AbstractUiNotification notification = ...
NotificationsUi.getService().notify( asList( notification ) );
```

The `notification` must be a subclass of `AbstractUiNotification` where the `eventId` passed to the constructor must match the one from the extension.

The notifications plug-in also adds a preference page under *General > Notifications* that lets the user choose which notifications should be shown.

Comment: It looks like Mylyn notifications cannot be used in "pure" Eclipse4 RCP application though (a dependency to org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI).

Comment: I'm quite new to eclipse development and I tried the above scenario, it didn't work for me. @GaneshRaoB could you please share a snippet of your solution?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use the plugin org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui, which contains interesting classes to display notification(s) at the bottom right of the screen.