# Mylyn notification example for RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to use Mylyn notifications for an Eclipse plug-in project (RCP).
Can any one provide information on this.

Comment: There is a blog post that explains how to use Mylyn notifications: https://resheim.net/2011/04/using-mylyn-notifications.html Did you read this?

Comment: Yes. But i was not able to find from which Plugin extension point 'org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.notifications' is exposed.

Comment: I think the required plugins are `o.e.m.n.core`, `o.e.m.n.feed`, `o.e.m.n.ui` which can be obtained from the http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest p2 repository.

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110234/java-rcp-swt-android-toast-like-dialog-in-eclipse-rcp