# How to use mylyn notifications extensions in Eclipse RCP Application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, mylyn

I am new to Eclipse development and I need to use mylyn notifications. I have referred [1], [2], [3], but I still couldn't get it to work.

This is my code now.

```
AbstractNotification  notification = new  AbstractNotification ("my.event" ) {
            public  String getLabel() { 
                return   "My Label";  
            } 
            public  String getDescription(){
                return "My Description";  
            }
            @Override
            public <T> T getAdapter(Class<T> adapter) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public Date getDate() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return new Date();
            } 
        }; 
NotificationsUi.getService().notify(Collections.singletonList(notification)) ;
```

This is the plugin.xml

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.ui.notifications">
    <event
        categoryId="org.eclipse.mylyn.builds.ui.category.Builds"
        id="my.event"
        label="My Event"
        selected="true">
        <defaultHandler
          sinkId="org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.sink.Popup">
        </defaultHandler>
      </event>
</extension>
```

What am I missing?

[1] [Mylyn notification example for RCP Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50147692/mylyn-notification-example-for-rcp-application)

[2] https://resheim.net/2011/04/using-mylyn-notifications.html

[3] https://krishnanmohan.wordpress.com/2012/10/06/scheduled-notifications-in-eclipse-rcp-applications/

Comment: Tell us what exactly isn't working.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann it gives a NullPointer exception.

Comment: Then, please add the stacktrace to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to get this done by using `AbstractNotificationPopUp` in Mylyn commons.ui. Hope this helps.